# How can I improve file download and upload speed in AWS EC2 and S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am currently computing an EC2 (T2-Micro) instance using Free-tier on AWS.

What this computer is doing is downloading the file from the web URL, saving it in the tmp path, and deleting the file in the tmp path after uploading S3.

But, I think my computer freezes often, stumbles, or takes too long to download. (minimum 0.1 MB / maximum 20 MB)

From what I looked into, the network speed of the T2-Micro was moderate or slow.

If the reason the server is stuttering is due to network speed, will it be solved if I change it to a different instance of Micro size?

In this case, would it be okay to change the specifications to T3-Micro or T4g-Micro?

[instancetype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA5xP.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "would it be okay to change"? You can certainly stop the instance, change the instance type, then start again. You might also want to look at the Monitoring tab in the EC2 console to see whether the instance is hitting any CPU problems. It would be helpful to have log files or some evidence to show that it is 'stumbling'.